Are these two SHA512 password hashes (of the same password and salt combo) interchangeable?
Consider the following two ways to generate a SHA512 password hash:
[I]
console.log(require("crypto").createHash("sha512").update("mysalt" + "mypassword").digest("base64"));
output:
yarunhSR9I6yzZYCn8KL/WINjXAFzFeS35Z2ykbaO0h8bY7mnkRSYcY+HfJYLA35XtuOSC8lIGOyssUUerTuhw==
[II]
openssl passwd -6 -salt mysalt mypassword
output:
$6$mysalt$Ts3752w7WPBw6ENoJhmynzPn47RFb2ze39cgq94y81EGSOvtYpxE6Tatj3ZREJqN5Qn.lBw7wL81kAod63xb5/
The outputs are very different - even if the $6$mysalt$ part from the second output is ignored.

Is it only a matter of encoding or something more?
Is it possible to derive one format from the other (by re-encoding etc.)?



Something more 2. No


In general, you can't recover the salt from just the hash. That's why the salt is included in plain text in II, so you can't go from I to II without additional information. There might be something you could do the other direction, but I'm not familiar enough with the format to be more specific.

Documentation on the underlying algorithms seems hard to find. If you can read Java, Apache Commons codec has a fairly clear and clean Java implementation showing the something more.

Also see the original specification at https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt.
